Text won't show up in html template
When I tried to integrate a html template I found online everything worked fine but the text just doesn't show up. I was following a tutorial where they made me use a static file to load in the site. Another problem I had is that I didn't understand what what to encase in {% static 'file name here'%}. Would appreciate if you could help with that too.
P.S. I used this template https://bootstrapmade.com/maxim-free-onepage-bootstrap-theme/
Down Below is a piece of the index.html from the template.
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>My Portfolio</title>
  <meta content="" name="description">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="{% static 'assets/img/favicon.png' %}" rel="icon">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png' %}" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="{% static 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/aos/aos.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
  <link href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- =======================================================
  * Template Name: Maxim
  * Template URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/maxim-free-onepage-bootstrap-theme/
  * Updated: Mar 17 2024 with Bootstrap v5.3.3
  * Author: BootstrapMade.com
  * License: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
  ======================================================== -->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">

      <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="{% static 'index.html' %}">Maxim</a></h1>
        <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
        <!-- <a href="index.html">{% static '="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>-->
      </div>

      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto active" href="#hero">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto " href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#team">Team</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Deep Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i></a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 5</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Drop Down 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
      </nav><!-- .navbar -->

    </div>
  </header><!-- End Header -->

  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="container text-center text-md-left" data-aos="fade-up">
      <h1>Welcome to Maxim</h1>
      <h2>We are team of talented designers making websites with Bootstrap</h2>
      <a href="#about" class="btn-get-started scrollto">Get Started</a>
    </div>
  </section><!-- End Hero -->


My website so far
I tried to reintegrate the template, looked at what the tutorial did and searched up similar problems online.

I'm guessing you're confusing two types of templates here, but maybe you just need to clarify more, and I'm misunderstanding.
The thing you downloaded I'd assume is a template, in the sense that you can modify the HTML text yourself to be whatever you want, manually to make your website.
The other kind of template, where stuff like {% static 'file name here'%} shows up, is where you have some incomplete HTML, and some preprocessor fills in data based on those tags.
For instance, although this would be sort of redundant in your case, you have
some static html file at /static/mytemplate.html. Then, wherever the templates are to be preprocessed, say, /templates/mypage.html, it could include
{ % static /static/mytemplate.html % }

And it would replace that brace with whatever is in that file.

Well, the template already had complete code without the {% static ' ' %}  I just needed to integrate it into the website itself. My issue is with the text not showing up  and the rest of the website being completely fine. If you compare my website https://i.sstatic.net/UmIQKViE.png and the template - it has text and mine doesn't. Hope this clarifies the issue.

What do you mean by integrate it into the website itself? How are you running the website?
You say the text isn't showing up, but without more context of how you're running the website, or the specific HTML you're using for it I can't say.
If I assume the HTML in your original post, I'd say the issue probably stems from not closing the tags  and , but maybe you just cut it off when pasting.
